# Correct usage of $\equiv$ and $\doteq$?

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

I defined two objects, one at an initial time $t_0$, called $A(t_0) = \{ x \; | \phi(t_0, \,x)\}$ with $\phi$ a binary predicate, and a second object defined for some time $t > t_0$, called $A(t) = \{ x \; | \phi(t, \,x) \}$. Now, to lighten the notation, I would just like to additionally define $A = A(t_0)$ and $\widetilde{A} = A(t)$. My attempt about the equality signs is the following:
$$
A \equiv A(t_0) \doteq \{ x \; | \phi(t_0, \,x) \}
$$
and
$$
\widetilde{A} \equiv A(t) \doteq \{ x \; | \phi(t, \,x) \}
$$
Mathematically, did I write correctly? Is it correct the usage of $\equiv$ and $\doteq$ ?

Comment: I've tidied your notation, but thereby introduced two assumptions: that only one $t$ is considered, and the the same $\phi$ defines each set. Please review, and change if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tidying up... yes, it is fine :)  Is it correct the usage of ≡ and ≐ ?

Comment: $\equiv$ and $\dot{=}$ are used in many different ways in many different areas of mathematics, so there's no single established definition on what they mean. do you know if the use of these symbols is "standard" in the field you are working in? ie, are you getting them from a particular textbook or paper?

Comment: thanks a lot for your nice reply! ...the field is complex networks / statistical physics...And I just would like to write those symbols correctly in my paper... since in the past I saw them in a variety of manuscripts with "ambiguous" meaning, I got my doubts....

Comment: @limone I think your usage looks fine :) ... just to assuage all concerns, I recommend putting a small "notation" section at the start of your paper, where you make clear how you'll be using different symbols!

Comment: Thanks a lot, very kind!